# rebind dataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, binding

My Project include dataGridView Control, and i change the property: gridview1.columns.DataPropertyName at run time
Now, i need rebind my gridView, how i do this.
in asp.net is simple gridView1.DataBind(), bun how in c#.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **DataSource** again, as in:

```
gridview1.DataSource = <your data source goes here>;
```

Comment: You may have to set the gridview1.DataSource to null first to force it to recognize that something has changed.
gridview1.DataSource = null;
gridview1.DataSource = <your data source goes here>;

Comment: Hello Adel, 
This is not work.. 
i know that in asp.net you can simple do : datagridview1.DataBind()
anyone has another solution to rebind gridview?